# Maharal on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, maharal

I am looking for work of the Maharal on Rosh Hashana and hopefully Yom Kipur. can someone help me?

Comment: The Be'er Hagolah ?

Comment: Nethivoth Olam Nethiv HaTeshuva: https://www.sefaria.org/Netivot_Olam%2C_Netiv_Hatshuva.1?lang=bi

Comment: He didn't write a separate sefer on the holidays of tishrei

Comment: @sam what does that sefer have to do with RH and YK?

Comment: Its has ideas on Rosh hahshana about simanim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maharal doesn't have any book entirely dedicated to these two holidays, but his short [Derasha for Shabbat Teshuva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14198&st=&pgnum=64) is about Yom Hakkippurim.

For more, you might also be able to look through his commentary to aggadot on relevant tractates. The Machon Yerushalayim edition of Maharal's books (some on Hebrewbooks.org) also have extensive indexes, so you might be able to find something there (for example, the [entry for Rosh Hashshana in the index to Netsach Yisra'el](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42852&st=&pgnum=276)).

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%92) I see that he wrote a book called **Shamayim Vaarets** on Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur. But I don't know how to find it.

Comment: Read further down the page - אך לשלושת ספריו: ספר הגדולה, ספר ההוד, וספר שמים וארץ לא ידוע מה עלה בגורלם. יש הסוברים כי ספרים אלו נכתבו ואבדו

Comment: Ah. thank you @ba